# Finding the probability from two separate probabilities

Tags: probability

Here's a completely fabricated example to demonstrate my question:

```
We know:
People named Joe have a 70% chance of becoming rock stars.
People with blond hair have a 30% chance of becoming rock stars.
```

**Is there a formula for the percentage chance that a blond guy named Joe will be a rock star?** Is it an average 
(50%)? Does one outweigh the other? Is there no meaningful correlation at all?

And if the two are unrelated and therefore we cannot combine them in any way, then can we still know which of the two probabilities to apply to blond Joe? If I say 70% am I wrong? I can just as easily apply the 30% to him.

I'm a smart guy, but not at all proficient in statistics, so I'm looking for a layman answer that doesn't have to be completely dumbed down.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is not enough information.  It could be anywhere from $0$ to $100\%$.  Imagine for a hypothetical scenario that in the world there are a total of ten people named Joe overall and a total of ten people with blond hair, three of which with blond hair are named Joe.  The remaining seven Joe's all have black hair.  The remaining seven blond people are named Bob.

Now... here are two possible scenarios, each unable to be distinguished from the details you have given so far:

- The three blond Joe's are all rockstars

This would lead to the probability that a blond Joe is a rockstar as being $100\%$

- None of the three blond Joes are rockstars.  That is, all of the rockstar Joe's are blackhaired and all of the rockstar blondes are named Bob.

This would lead to a probability that a blonde Joe is a rockstar as being $0\%$.

Of course, the specific numbers could be literally anywhere between those.  To give any further information we would need to make several heavy assumptions as to the relationship between being a Joe, being blonde, and being a rockstar.  We know that one such assumption such as "being a joe, being a blonde and being a rockstar are all independent events" cannot be true otherwise the chance of being a rockstar should have been the same for Joes as it is for blondes.

---

As per the edited question:

What you are talking about is [conditional probability](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conditional_probability).  The notation $Pr(A\mid B)$ is the probability that $A$ occurs given that $B$ has occurred.

Let $J$ be the event that a randomly selected person is named Joe.  Let $R$ be the event that a randomly selected person is a rockstar.  Let $B$ be the event that a randomly selected person has blond hair.

Your givens are that $Pr(R\mid J)=0.7$ and that $Pr(R\mid B)=0.3$, that is to say the probability that a randomly selected Joe is a rockstar is $0.7$ and that a randomly selected person with blond hair is a rockstar is $0.3$.

You ask what the probability that a randomly selected person whose name is Joe and who has blond hair is a rock star.  I.e. you are asking for $Pr(R\mid J\cap B)$.  As mentioned previously, there is not enough given information to determine this and this number could have little to nothing to do with the values of $Pr(R\mid J)$ and $Pr(R\mid B)$.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. The thing I'm still not getting (and I will update my question) is: If we can't combine them, can we still know which of the two probabilities to apply to blond Joe? If I say 70% am I wrong? I can just as easily apply the 30% to him.

Comment: @Shades included another section, but the short answer is still that you cannot apply either since the values of $70\%$ and $30\%$ are if we **only** know that the person is a Joe or the person is blonde and we know nothing else about them.  The only situations where I can say for certain is, *assuming blonde joes exist* that if either of your initially given probabilities were $0\%$ or $100\%$ that we could conclude what the final probability is.  E.g. if we know all blonde people are rockstars, then clearly a blonde joe must be a rockstar too.

Comment: @Shades that there *isn't* such a formula to get a final resulting probability is proven above by the fact that I gave you two scenarios, both with your initial assumptions, which resulted in two entirely different probabilities.  Had there been such a formula this wouldn't have been possible to do.

Comment: So, absent a correlation between the two (being blond and being Joe), the introduction of one actually negates the presence of the other. Is that correct?

Comment: "*The introduction of one negates the presence of the other*" I do not understand what you mean to say by this, but it is almost certainly wrong.  If someone is blond and joe, then he is most certainly blond *and* joe... just because we learn that the blond person's name is joe doesn't stop him from being blond, but it does stop us from using information that we know about *arbitrary* blond people because our blond person is no longer *just any arbitrary* blond person, it is a *blond joe* so info about blond people isn't specific enough anymore to mean anything.

Comment: Negates the information we have about the probability of him being a rock star. Meaning, it would be better if we only knew one of those things (Joe, 70%, or blond, 30%) rather than have both and not know anything about the relationship to being a rock star.

Comment: Why would it be "better"?  I can't imagine any scenario where having more information is worse.  In the end, it comes down to a question of where the data came from in the first place.  If someone ran a poll to see how many rockstars were blond and how many rockstars were named Joe and compared these to the whole population, they *should* have also kept track of how many rockstars were both blond and joe and how many blonde joes there are in the population, giving you exactly the information you are looking for.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/63337/discussion-between-jmoravitz-and-shades).